# Need to remove duplicate rows in a list report based on a logical preference (IBM cognos 10)

Tags: cognos-10

I have two tables in my data base and I am joining them together by ID. For both tables the key is a combination of ID and a time dimension (lets say year). In my first table there are multiple rows for each ID. I want to be able to remove the duplicate rows in my output with a preference based on a time dimension. Here is an example of an entry in my table.

```
(for the following schemea): ID     attribute1     attribute2      year
                            9999    1              1               2014
                            9999    2              2               2012
```

I would like the first entry to get preference over the second entry. I know I could create a filter for the exact year that I want, only for each record the most recent year might be different. I need to be able to remove all duplicates with a preference for rows that have the most recent year. Does anybody know how to do this in cognos report studio? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Use this filter:

```
[year] = maximum([year] for [ID])
```

We get the maximum year for each unique ID and we drop rows where the year column does not match that value.

This assumes that there are no rows with both the same ID and the same year which seems like a safe assumption based on your description.